# Custom map for website

Tags: html, flash, google-maps

I have an overview drawing of a plant and I want to show the important pieces of equipment. Each piece of equipment would show some description information and have a link whenever it is hovered over.

I want the whole thing to function similarly to Google Maps where I can zoom in and pan around.

I have been trying to get the basic pan and zoom functions to work in Flash but are there better ways to develop this? Maybe something that doesn't involve Flash?

Comment: have you considered using the Custom Overlays that Google Maps API v3 offers? If you have the overview drawing, and it is accurate - and if you have the GPS coordinates of the plant's 4 corners in the overview drawing, you can essentially overlay that drawing onto google maps and have it act the way you want (panning and zooming). You can then use jquery/css to trigger hover/click events on the different parts of your overlay. It's just one thought that came to me to solve this problem.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays take a look at that link and view the example in the document, it may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go for a flash-free, google maps-free plugin, you can combine http://wayfarerweb.com/jquery/plugins/mapbox/ with some jQuery for the mouseover behaviours.

It of course depends on how comfortable you are using jQuery, the implementation of the map itself is quite easy (it has zoom and pan), and the hovers are not complicated but will require more research if you haven't worked with javascript before. The advantage is that you will have complete control over it...